# Name Column will not sort Alphabetically in R after merging two 3 data sets

Tags: r, merge

Merged 3 data sets in R. Cannot get the name column to sort alphabetically after the final merge. I can get it to work in SAS but for some reason, the sort function is not working in R for this column.

```
Grades <-read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
Grades2 <-read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
Grades3 <-read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)

#add Grades2 to Grades
combined1 <- merge (Grades, Grades2)

#adding Grades3 to Combined1
combined2<- rbind (combined1, Grades3)

#sorting the data alphabetically and only displaying the first 5 rows
sorted <- combined2[sort.default(combined2$Name),]
sorted[1:5,]
```

As you can see the last 3 names on the list are what were appended through rbind, when I attempt to sort the data alphabetically, this is my output, which is exactly the same as it was previous to sorting. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
sorted[1:29,]
Name

1   Aldrin
2   Becky
3   Carl
4   Daphne
5   Eriksen
6   Frank
7   Gary
8   Hobbs
9   Isabella
10  Jeanette
11  Kevin
12  Lily
13  Mickey
14  Nora
15  Oprah
16  Patrice
17  Quinn
18  Robin
19  Stella
20  Tracy
21  Ursula
22  Victoria
23  Wendy
24  Xander
25  Yasmine
26  Zoey
27  Ted
28  Barney
29  Marshall

> dput(Grades)
structure(list(Name = structure(1:26, .Label = c("Aldrin", "Becky", 
"Carl", "Daphne", "Eriksen", "Frank", "Gary", "Hobbs", "Isabella", 
"Jeanette", "Kevin", "Lily", "Mickey", "Nora", "Oprah", "Patrice", 
"Quinn", "Robin", "Stella", "Tracy", "Ursula", "Victoria", "Wendy", 
"Xander", "Yasmine", "Zoey"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Assignment1 = c(98L, 100L, 95L, 57L, 83L, 46L, 86L, 68L, 
    98L, 74L, 81L, 49L, 66L, 66L, 92L, 51L, 60L, 54L, 61L, 54L, 
    80L, 52L, 50L, 94L, 84L, 64L), Assignment2 = c(56L, 54L, 
    69L, 79L, 98L, 89L, 83L, 57L, 85L, 92L, 61L, 87L, 63L, 47L, 
    86L, 100L, 77L, 41L, 50L, 72L, 80L, 59L, 47L, 45L, 68L, 40L
    ), Assignment3 = c(81L, 100L, 48L, 82L, 72L, 78L, 72L, 82L, 
    88L, 78L, 62L, 52L, 75L, 42L, 52L, 79L, 42L, 89L, 53L, 71L, 
    99L, 46L, 64L, 66L, 77L, 71L), Assignment4 = c(94L, 99L, 
    93L, 46L, 85L, 67L, 87L, 73L, 63L, 48L, 87L, 97L, 75L, 88L, 
    59L, 75L, 84L, 65L, 89L, 86L, 70L, 84L, 63L, 91L, 93L, 71L
    )), .Names = c("Name", "Gender", "Assignment1", "Assignment2", 
"Assignment3", "Assignment4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))

> dput(Grades2)
structure(list(Name = structure(1:26, .Label = c("Aldrin", "Becky", 
"Carl", "Daphne", "Eriksen", "Frank", "Gary", "Hobbs", "Isabella", 
"Jeanette", "Kevin", "Lily", "Mickey", "Nora", "Oprah", "Patrice", 
"Quinn", "Robin", "Stella", "Tracy", "Ursula", "Victoria", "Wendy", 
"Xander", "Yasmine", "Zoey"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Assignment5 = c(97L, 53L, 81L, 64L, 97L, 52L, 62L, 98L, 91L, 
    81L, 91L, 99L, 81L, 76L, 54L, 59L, 59L, 81L, 57L, 83L, 82L, 
    78L, 58L, 89L, 67L, 89L), Assignment6 = c(100L, 100L, 52L, 
    62L, 90L, 96L, 76L, 67L, 95L, 82L, 91L, 81L, 89L, 93L, 55L, 
    60L, 68L, 81L, 69L, 55L, 50L, 92L, 97L, 69L, 89L, 96L), Assignment7 = c(81L, 
    81L, 99L, 100L, 78L, 79L, 100L, 94L, 69L, 95L, 81L, 89L, 
    62L, 91L, 95L, 50L, 71L, 58L, 91L, 92L, 80L, 70L, 71L, 67L, 
    71L, 97L)), .Names = c("Name", "Gender", "Assignment5", "Assignment6", 
"Assignment7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))

> dput(Grades3)
structure(list(Name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Barney", 
"Marshall", "Ted"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "M", class = "factor"), Assignment1 = c(99L, 
93L, 96L), Assignment2 = c(82L, 98L, 90L), Assignment3 = c(88L, 
92L, 99L), Assignment4 = c(81L, 80L, 96L), Assignment5 = c(94L, 
91L, 94L), Assignment6 = c(98L, 85L, 89L), Assignment7 = c(81L, 
94L, 85L)), .Names = c("Name", "Gender", "Assignment1", "Assignment2", 
"Assignment3", "Assignment4", "Assignment5", "Assignment6", "Assignment7"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `sort.default(combined2$Name)` or just `sort(combined2$Name)`

Comment: I just want it to put the last names in alphabetical order, I have tried sort and sort.default, both give me the same result. Sorry, I am pretty novice.

Comment: Actually the sample my professor provided utilizes sort(combined2$Name)

Comment: When I attempt to show the just the first 5 results, I get Aldrin, Beck, Carl, Daphne, Eriksen.  It should be Aldrin, Barney, Becky, Carl, Daphne.  So I tried the sort function for the whole column and it keeps returning it as it was right after I merged the two data sets. Not in alphabetical order

Comment: are you assigning the result back after sorting? `combined2$Name <- sort(combined2$Name)`

Comment: My guess is that your `Name` column is actually a `factor`. Try converting it to character using `paste` or `as.character` and see if sorting works then.

Comment: Try `dplyr:: arrange(combined2,Name)`

Comment: I think it is has to do with the name column, I have tried all of the above code and it is still giving me the same issue, how would I use the paste or as.character to convert it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your post with `dput(Grades)`, `dput(Grades2)` and `dput(Grades3)` and also include your expected output. Right now, all we are doing is guessing.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Enter `dput(Grades)` in the console and copy whatever output you get and edit your post above, do the same for `Grades2` and `Grades3`.

Comment: Thank you and what is your expected output for this data?

Comment: 1   Aldrin  28 Barney   2   Becky   3   Carl  4   Daphne  in that order. It would include the rest of the row data also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile all the comments above into answer, you need to first convert `Name` from `factor` to `character` and then use `order` to sort it by `Name`

```
combined2$Name <- as.character(combined2$Name)
combined2 <- combined2[order(combined2$Name), ]
combined2

#       Name Gender Assignment1 Assignment2 Assignment3 Assignment4 ...
#1    Aldrin      M          98          56          81          94 ...
#28   Barney      M          93          98          92          80 ...
#2     Becky      F         100          54         100          99 ...
#3      Carl      M          95          69          48          93 ...    
#....
```

Or using `dplyr` with same logic

```
library(dplyr)
combined2 <- combined2 %>% mutate(Name = as.character(Name)) %>% arrange(Name)
```

Comment: it does work if I want it to read the whole list, how would I get it to just produce the first five in the list alphabetically?

Comment: @JJRN like this `combined2[1:5, ]` to display first 5 rows.

Comment: Thank you! You are my hero :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have marked it solved, thank you for being so kind.